# vagrant up command fails to find any box

Tags: vagrant, virtualization, virtualbox, vm

**The issue:**
For any vagrant box, whenever I run the vagrant up command, I get the following error:
[image: Box could not be found. An unknown option was passed in to libcurl]

This even happened when I tried the centos/7 box instead.

**What I have tried:**

- Tried having VirtualBox window open while running vagrant up command
- Installing the latest VC Redist for my AMD64 (x64) and Also tried (x86) VC Redist.
- Followed instructions in the following video, as a previous video of this channel resolved my CentOS 9 issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FeqyzY4Y14
- Modifying the Vagrantfile; I added a line `config.vm.box_download_insecure=true` below `config.vm.box`

However, the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was Firewall/Antivirus. When I disabled Antivirus Protection and ran the `vagrant up` command again, Vagrant worked fine, and launched the VM based on VagrantFile configurations.